# JPA equivalent of @DynamicUpdate, @SelectBeforeUpdate

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, jpa

How do I implement the Hibernate's @SelectBeforeUpdate behavior with standard JPA?

My problem is that I have two concurrent threads that read the same object, modify two different attributes, and save to the database: the last writing thread overwrites the modifications done by the first thread, thus "resetting" the attribute to the initial state.

Comment: There is no such thing in the JPA spec (which is why Hibernate has its own annotations to do it). So, if you're using Hibernate as your JPA provider, just use the Hibernate annotations. If not, read the documentation of your provider to see if it provides something similar.